# Furnace extinction pop

Tags: furnace, natural-gas, gas-burner

I have a newer central air unit, amana updraft w/ng furnace).  Everything works fine on the unit and has no issues except everytime the thermostat reaches the set heat temp when it calls the heat to shut off the gas will explode or pop as the flame is extinguished. This is referred to as “extinction pop” apparently and there is little to no info on the issue anywhere.  But when the desired temp is met, the sequence is extinguish flame while blower and inducer still run for another 30 seconds or so before shutting off.  So EVERYTIME when the flame extinguishes it will explode, the blower will still be blowing on its cool down time and exhaust draft inducer will still be blowing as they both should. The only issue is the gas popping when extinguished, real loud and every time enough you can visually see the furnace door push out from the pressure.  It has nothing to do with the vents popping from pressure, heat differential, metal ducting bending or inadequate air flow as the filter is new and i keep it changed.  The vent/ return are at the proper separation temps.  Theres not a bunch of registers blocked or dampers closed as i have none and vents dont close.  I know the exhaust and intake are both clear and to code with only 10 feet of pipe to the outside.. the heat exchanger is fine with no rollout while heating and pure blue flames going directly into the flame tubes.  Clean burners and orifices.  But started doing this after the 2nd winter, is only 4 years old.  Condensate seems normal as the pump is still filling and draining as it should.  Amana/ goodman say its not normal but couldnt say what the issue might be.  Im worried it will blow apart the heat exchanger eventually or worse the gas valve be the issue.  Had hvac company tell me its the gas valve and their issue but gas company say its a furnace issue.  All i know is its loud enough to wake me up and make me jump every friggn time, sometimes is more intense than others..  not sure what to do or whether its normal or what the issue would be as it didnt do this for the first few years and now does it everytime..  ignition is fine.  Never had any sensors trip or any errors on the system..

Comment: You will get more useful help here if you give the model number of your furnace and break your post into paragraphs to make it less challenging to read. Use the EDIT button below your post.

Comment: Did HVAC and/or gas come and check, or just tell you over the phone?

Comment: Hvac dude came and checked it but was a waste of time and money to me because he didnt take his hands out of his pockets the whole time.   He stood and watched it do it and said “yeah your right thats an extinction pop alright. Only gas company is allowed to touch the valves and thats whats causing it.”   The gas company dispatched a tech, the tech called me and gave me the 20 questions about what was going on and told me that “its got to be a clog or issue with the flame tubes, heat exchanger or the orifices on the actual furnace and we dont do hvac work”.  So got me nowhere and costs 60$.

Comment: I tried making it into paragraphs but phone screwed up and erased all the editing.  And model number?  Its an updraft natural gas amana / goodman furnace..  it was put in brand new 4 or 5 years ago.  Its got 4 burners and it goes boom when fire goes out.  If i leave the top door off when its running it still pops except its just a wee little poot compared to the boom when sealed and door on..  dont ever smell gas around it unless the dog got into the trash again..